# Please let me know .if you able to resolve the issue?

Tags: google-colaboratory

how to select python3 from runtime type in google colab. No such option in it.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 is now the default. You cannot choose Python 2 anymore.

So, for now, Python = Python3.